# same json objects values

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

```
"RestInfo": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "store_id": "3",
            "staff_id": "1075",
            "default_rest": "0",
            "restaurant_name": "Imagine Restaurant",
            "restaurant_location": "Sydney",
},
 {
            "id": "3",
            "store_id": "3",
            "staff_id": "1085",
            "default_rest": "0",
            "restaurant_name": "MealsAustralia",
            "restaurant_location": "Nsw",
},



NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

NSArray *array=[jsonArray objectForKey:@"RestInfo"];

for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"the restrunt==%@",[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"restaurant_location"]);
```

I can only get one json value, but I need get more values please help me, I am very new to objective C.

Comment: Explain more about what you want....!!!

Comment: There is no `]` at the and of the JSON array structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an array of dictionary you need to fetch the values from dictionary:

```
    for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *dicObj = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@", [dicObj objectForKey:@"id"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [dicObj objectForKey:@"store_id"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [dicObj objectForKey:@"staff_id"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [dicObj objectForKey:@"default_rest"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [dicObj objectForKey:@"restaurant_name"]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [dicObj objectForKey:@"restaurant_location"]);
     }
```

Comment: Guys - we've had Objective C literals for almost 2 years now! Time to get used to concise notation :-)    http://blog.bignerdranch.com/398-objective-c-literals-part-1/

Comment: Good point +1, Thanks.

Comment: its works fine i need to display those values into table view

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++)

NSLog(@"the restrunt==%@",[array addObject:[[[jsonArray objectForKey:@"RestInfo"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"restaurant_location"]];
```

Comment: I have not tried it,wrote it here..but I think it should work.